# Defining Multiple Variables with the Same Value

Tags: variable-definitions

I know we have

```
a := 1
b := 1
```

but is there some 1-liner shorthand, akin to:

```
a, b := 1 (* I know this doesn't work, but I'm just using it as an example *)
```

?

Comment: It works for `=` which is what is enough for `1` anyway. Or do you insist on `SetDelayed`?

Comment: You can try a=b=1

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with lazy evaluation (i.e., `:=`)?

Comment: @George The `:=` assignment is *delayed*, not *lazy*. For [*lazy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) you need [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) as well.

Comment: @Kuba and @"bill s" seem to have the answer and should post?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function that does what you want:

```
SetAttributes[DotEqual, HoldAll]
DotEqual[a__, v_] := With[
    {rhs = Thread[Table[Hold[v],Length[Hold[a]]], Hold]},
    Replace[rhs, Hold[x_] :> ({a} := x)];
]
```

Then:

```
Clear[a, b];
x := Print[1];
DotEqual[a, b, x]
```

This produces the desired [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues) with no evaluation leaks:

```
OwnValues[a]
OwnValues[b]
```

> {HoldPattern[a] :> x}
>
> {HoldPattern[b] :> x}

The reason I chose [`DotEqual`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DotEqual) as the function name is that it already has an infix notation (entered by using <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>). So:

```
Clear[a, b];
x := Print[1];
a ≐ b ≐ x
```

Check:

```
OwnValues[a]
OwnValues[b]
```

> {HoldPattern[a] :> x}
>
> {HoldPattern[b] :> x}